# Passing HTML to client in Python Flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am saving state of a web page as html. I got the saving part working. I have problems in sending the html back to the client to reestablish state. Currently I try to send my state as json from the server like this:

```
@app.route("report_page", methods=["GET"])
def report_page():
return render_template(
    "report_input.html",
    form=form,      
    step_table_state= json.dumps({"test": html_state["step_table_html"]}),
)
```

From the client side I receive the html like this:

```
let test = JSON.parse({{ step_table_state }});
```

...but some characters, like double qoutes are escaped:

```
let test = JSON.parse({&#34;test&#34;: &#34;&lt;table class=\&#34;table table-striped\&#34; id=\&#34;stepsTable\&#34;&gt;&lt....etc....
```

Within this framework, how can I transfer my html state to the client - or, is there a jQuery or JavaScript function that could get my original html back?

Comment: Have you tried `let test = JSON.parse({{ step_table_state | safe }});` ?

Comment: I tried, but forgot the " | tojson " and " | safe " flags. The text looks as it should now. Thanks @arsho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tojson` Jinja filter:

```
let test = {{ step_table_state | tojson }};
```

More about it [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#tojson) and [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters).